# get LDAP server ip(s) by php

Tags: php, ldap

Is there any way to find out the `LDAP server ip(s)` by using php code? I didn't found anything related to what I want So there is nothing I try. Just reading [Ldap](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php) and found nothing for get `LDAP server ip` by php.

Comment: Are you trying to discover LDAP servers on a network or are you trying to get the IP address of a particular LDAP server using the hostname?

Comment: I am trying to get ldap server ip where I am working

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following drop in function to get the LDAP servers in a given domain:

```
/**
 * Get an array of all the LDAP servers for a domain by querying DNS.
 *
 * @param string $domain The domain name to query.
 * @return string[]
 */
function getLdapServersForDomain($domain)
{
    $hosts = dns_get_record('_ldap._tcp.'.$domain, DNS_SRV);

    return is_array($hosts) ? array_column($hosts, 'target') : [];
}
```

Where `$domain` is the fqdn, such as `mydomain.com`.

That will get the LDAP server names. If you really need the IP addresses instead I could add some additional logic to it for you. This also assumes at least PHP 5.5 with the use of `array_column`.

Comment: returning blank array when I `print_r(getLdapServersForDomain("mydomain.com"));`

Comment: Do you have your works DNS servers configured on your server? This essentially just does a DNS lookup for the LDAP service records. It could fail if for some reason they don't exist or your your server isn't looking at your internal DNS. Is this AD/OpenLDAP, or something else?

Comment: Don't know need to check.